# Angular 6 change value depending on locale

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have an app with in which I have two values for a translatable field such as: name_es for spanish and name_en for english.

Is there a way I can change the value in the template depending on the locale?

What I need is that if I am in english the displayed value is name_en and if I am in spanish I use name_es.

Regards

Comment: Yes. Take a look at `@ngx/translate` it makes localization very simple and straightforward. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to do it with the included i18n functionality. Tought that replacing in my localized messages the equiv-text="{{ event.name_en }}" would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this the following way:

In my translation file there is this translation unit:

```
<trans-unit id="fa5f79882ea84c0027e851ef6e417e53b55109ed" datatype="html">
    <source><x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{ country.name_en }}"/></source>
    <target>{{ country.name_es }}</target>
    <context-group purpose="location">
      <context context-type="sourcefile">app/about-iica/about-iica.component.ts</context>
      <context context-type="linenumber">18</context>
    </context-group>
    <context-group purpose="location">
      <context context-type="sourcefile">app/about-iica/about-iica.component.ts</context>
      <context context-type="linenumber">20</context>
    </context-group>
  </trans-unit>
```

Notice the section `<target>{{ country.name_es }}</target>`

By switching that section I'm rendering the variable name_es instead of name_en.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [doc](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) you can use the new angular i18n module,

Comment: I have already read the documentation but I don't find how can I change the displayed variable. Example: <source><x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{ contribucion.name_es }}"/></source> translate it to <source><x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{ contribucion.name_en }}"/></source>

Comment: Follow this example: “Deploying an i18n Angular app with angular-cli” @feloy2 https://medium.com/@feloy/deploying-an-i18n-angular-app-with-angular-cli-fc788f17e358

Comment: Thanks managed to solve it by myself! I will answer the question